# What does "void" mean as the return type of a method?

Tags: java

I'm confused about "void",
as it pertains to methods.

I don't know what the distinction between two methods is when one has "void" and another doesn't.

For example, if I do:

```
Public meth (int amount)
{

    amount = initial * interest;
    return amount;

}
```

( not sure if it was right, or even valid, to take the name "amount" and name it the same thing as my formal parameter, but what makes sense here is that you're performing a calculation and returning the result)

Then, if I did something like:

```
Public void Testing (int array[])
{

    //code that would modify the internals of an array

}
```

Would the second one have no "return" because it's more of a general method, that can be applied to any integer array, while the first one is about doing work on specific variables?

Would also appreciate one or two more examples of when I would or wouldn't be using "void" and "return".

One other thing that seems to confuse me is calling methods.

I know sometimes I'll do something like, for example, using the Testing method above,

```
Testing(ArrayName);
```

Other times, it will be like:

```
NameOfWhateverImApplyingMethodTo.MethodName();
```

And then there are times when things will be done properly by:

```
Thing1.MethodName(Thing2);
```

Which circumstances would I switch the syntax for method calls like this?

Comment: If you have two questions, you should ask two questions. The question about "void" is enough for one question. You should make the "calling methods" part a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return type is what you get out of it. When you call it, what are you hoping to get back? For instance, if the method gets the average of two numbers, then you're expecting a number back, so the return type will be a number type, like "int" (integer).
You can see what it should be using that logic or by looking in the method for the word return - what comes after return is what is returned, and its type should be declared in the method (e.g. if it says "return 4;" it's returning an int, and should be e.g. public int getFour()

You also asked about e.g. testing() vs testing(word)
I remember having the same difficulty. The distinction between the two also relates to the method declaration line. I'll illustrate.

```
    public String testing(){
        return "a word";
    }
```

Calling this method by doing "System.out.println(testing());" should print "a word". Calling this method by doing "System.out.println(testing("a word"));" will give you an issue - this is because when you call testing, it looks at the appropriate method: one in the right class, with the right return type and with the right *arguments/parameters*. If you're calling testing("a word"), that means you're using a String as an argument (because "a word" is a string), and so it tries to use the testing(String aString) method - which doesn't exist.
So you use empty brackets when the method takes no input, and you put stuff in brackets when the method expects stuff. This should be less confusing than it sounds, because it's usually logical - if you want to call a method that returns an average, you need to ask yourself "Average of *what*?" You'd probably need to supply it with the values you want the average of.

Moving on: (a) testing() versus(b) AClass.testing() versus(c) aclass.testing() -

In (a), there's no class specified. Therefore, if you call it from that class, Java can guess which class: this one, and it'll work. From any other class, it won't know what you're talking about, and might even insult you.
In (b), you're specifying a class in general - therefore it'll know what class to find it in - and it'll work if it's a "static method". *[see bottom]
In (c), you're specifying an *instance* of AClass you want to run "testing()" on*.

For instance, imagine you've created a class called Business. You make a hundred Business objects by specifying for each a name, number, address.
e.g.

```
   Business b = new Business(name, number, address);
```

Then in the Business class you have a method "getName()". This method takes no argument - you could see that the brackets are empty - so if, from another class, you call "Business.getName()", how could it know which name you want? You've just made a hundred businesses!
It simply can't. Therefore, for such a method, you'd call "b.getName()" (b being the Business we created above) and it would get the name for *this instance* of a Business - namely, b.
I'm happy to help, so if you're confused about any particular parts of what I just wrote please let me know and I'll try to elaborate!

edit: A bit on static methods:
Static methods don't belong to an instance of the class. getName(), for example, would get the name of *this* Business - ie, this instance of the Business class.  But let's say that in the Business class you made a method that took the first letter of each word in a String and transformed it to uppercase - like if you wanted to make the business names look more professional when you printed them out.

```
public static String stringToUpperCase(String aString){
    aString = aString.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + aString.substring(1);
    return aString;
}
```

And to use that, you change the getName() method from:

```
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
```

to

```
public String getName(){
    return stringToUpperCase(name);
}
```

The new method is used here to make the name have an uppercase first letter - but that is the extent of its involvement with the Business class. You notice it doesn't ask for information about the name, address, or number for a particular business. It just takes a string you give it, does something to it, and gives it back. It doesn't matter whether you have no Businesses or a hundred.
To call this method, you'd use:

```
System.out.println(Business.stringToUpperCase("hello"));
```

This would print Hello.
If it were not a static method, you'd have to make a new Business first:

```
Business b = new Business("aName", "aNumber", "anAddress"); 

System.out.println(b.stringToUpperCase("hello"));
```

And if the method *did* need access to more Business-instance information (like a business's name number or address) it wouldn't be able to be an instance variable.

Comment: I appreciate all of the replies, but this one is really doing it for me.

Comment: That's feels rly good to hear :) It wasn't too long ago I struggled with this stuff, so time-permitting I'll try to make myself available to you - you can message me with questions StackOverflow won't accept and I'll try to answer them

Comment: And hit the check next to the answer please

Comment: I'm thinking about what I've been practicing, and it all makes sense.                          Methods need a type, or else it would be a constructor, which is called when I make a new object (class instance) or define the class and the parameters for it in the class file, right?          If you could just explain a little more about what you meant by saying AClass.testing() will work if testing is a static method, this would be perfect!

Comment: Exactly! and re the static method, see my answer - i edited it

Comment: Wow! I pretty much get 99% of it all now! Thanks a lot, Ed! I don't know how to message you, but thank you. I will hit the check mark now.

Comment: Terrific. Now I want to scratch at that 1%.. Although 99% may put you ahead of me
Try me though. I'll try to answer either tonight or tomorrow

Comment: It says I don't have enough reputation to move this to chat, so it looks like this is going to have to be my very last comment or it seems a moderator might get involved. I was just going to say I pretty much understood every single thing there until you mentioned "instance variables"

Comment: True I don't actually know how chat works I just assumed it worked like they usually do.. my bad :( 
In my Business class example, Businesses have names, numbers, and addresses - and each Business has a copy (aka "instance")

Answer (score 1):

1. Java is case sensitive, so the modifier `Public` is invalid, use `public`
2. You can't define a method as `public methodName(int a)`, only a constructor has this signature, a method must be `public void methodName(<signature>)` for methods that don't return anything or `public <return type> methodName(<signature>)` for methods that do.

Answer (score 1):

Void basically means that the method will not return anything.

If you did

```
String name= "tim";
public void getName(){
 return name;
}
```

This would result in an error, because the getName method is returning a string object called name, but the method declaration is saying I am returning nothing - because it is void.

Instead the method should be :

```
String name = "tim";
public String getName(){
return name;
}
```

Now when the method getName() is called it will return a string object "name" with "tim" inside of it :)

You might have void for a set method. So for example

```
String name = "tim";
public void setName(String newName){
this.name = newName;
}
```

When this method is called you would use `setName("Andy");` and it would set the value of the name variable to be "Andy". Nothing is returned in this method, because it is setting something, but there is no need to send anything back, so we use void on the method declaration.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The method that has `void` as return type does not return anything. For example you want to set a field `firstName` in your class. You will write a setting method like

```
public void setFirstName(String n) {
 this.firstName = n;
}
```

As you can see you are just setting a class variable and does not require to return anything.

If you dont use void then you have to provide a return type for method. Like if you wish to write a getter for above variable as:

```
public String getFirstName() {
 return this.firstName;
}
```

Once you provide a return type, you will have to return a value of that type otherwise your code will not compile.

Calling a method can be done based on where you are calling it from and what modifier is used:

- If you are calling the method from the same class then you can simply write `firstName = getFirstName()`
- If you are calling the method from another class then you require object of method's class as qualifier like `personObject.getFirstName()`
- If you are calling a static method then you require class name as qualifier like `Person.getFirstName();`

Answer (score 0):

The first example, a method without a return type at all, is a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html); used when an instance is created with `new`. However, you can't return a value from a constructor. Something like,

```
this.amount = initial * interest; // return amount;
```

Sets the field `amount` to `initial * interest`.